# Oracle Timezone Conversion

Tags: oracle, timezone

I am using the inbuilt oracle function from_tz for timezone conversion. Does anyone know if it takes into account daylight saving changes?

```
 to_char(from_tz(CAST(enteredondtm AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC') 
         AT TIME ZONE 'PST','YYYY-MM-DD') entered_on_date .
```

in this function the enteredondtm is in UTC which is converted to PST with this function. The conversion happens correctly. Just wanted to make sure it will happen during daylight savings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will take DST into consideration.

To convince yourself of that, substitute `date '2018-02-01'` for the column name `enteredondtm` in your formula and see what you get (use a full format model for TO_CHAR though, to see the time-of-day, not just the date). You will see that the output is 16:00 hours on the previous day. Then change that to `date '2018-08-01'` and you will see that the result is 17:00 hours on the previous day.

The `date` date literal has midnight as the time-of-day. During standard time, the Pacific time zone is eight hours behind UTC; during DST, it is seven hours behind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, simple proof:

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP '2018-06-01 00:00:00 PST',
    TIMESTAMP '2018-12-01 00:00:00 PST'
from dual;

01.06.2018 00:00:00 -07:00  01.12.2018 00:00:00 -08:00
```

However, why are you concerned about daylight savings if your output is `YYYY-MM-DD`, i.e. it does not contain any times?

Just a note, time zone `PST` can be ambiguous, see

```
SELECT TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME), TZNAME
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE TZABBREV = 'PST'; 

TZABBREV    TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)   TZNAME
========================================
PST -05:00  America/Bahia_Banderas
PST -06:00  America/Mazatlan
PST -06:00  America/Boise
PST -06:00  Mexico/BajaSur
PST -06:00  America/Inuvik
PST -07:00  America/Los_Angeles
PST -07:00  America/Hermosillo
PST -07:00  America/Ensenada
PST -07:00  America/Dawson_Creek
PST -07:00  America/Dawson
PST -07:00  America/Creston
PST -07:00  America/Santa_Isabel
PST -07:00  US/Pacific
PST -07:00  PST8PDT
PST -07:00  PST
PST -07:00  US/Pacific-New
PST -07:00  America/Tijuana
PST -07:00  America/Vancouver
PST -07:00  America/Whitehorse
PST -07:00  Canada/Pacific
PST -07:00  Canada/Yukon
PST -07:00  Mexico/BajaNorte
PST -08:00  America/Juneau
PST -08:00  America/Sitka
PST -08:00  Pacific/Pitcairn
PST -08:00  America/Metlakatla
```

Better use the "real" long name. There are only a few time zones (see `SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE TZABBREV = TZNAME`) where you can use the abbreviation without getting a `ORA-01882: timezone region not found` error.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the clarification. I have separate date and time columns. I missed posting the time column.

Comment: @ranjitunnikrishnan, if you have separate date and time columns the DST handling will be quite difficult. It is easier to use just one column. `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` values **always** contain a date and a time part.

Comment: does from_tz accept a column value as timezone ? something like --to_char(from_tz(CAST(enteredondtm AS TIMESTAMP),'UTC') 
         AT TIME ZONE column_value,'YYYY-MM-DD') entered_on_date . column_value is fetched dynamically . The values fetched are 'US\Eastern' , 'US\Pacific' (with the single quotes) .

Comment: everytime i use column names i get the following error ORA-01882: timezone region not found
01882. 00000 -  "timezone region not found"
*Cause:    The specified region name was not found.
*Action:   Contact Oracle Support Services.

Comment: It must be `US/Eastern` and `US/Pacific` - slash instead of backslash.

Comment: sorry it was a typo.. the values there are US/Eastern and US/Pacific.can you think of any other reason it will give the error?

Comment: No compare with the valid names.

Comment: Sorry to ask.. Can you explain a bit? Compare if the values are US/Eastern ?

Comment: No, compare your timezone with all valid names, i.e. `SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE TZNAME = ...`

Comment: figured it out. had to convert to char to_char(column name) and use it and it worked. Thanks for all your help and suggestions.